# Use a config file in jenkins pipeline

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline job, which is parametrized. It will take a string input and pass that to a bat script.

Input : https://jazz-test3.com/web/projects/ABC

I wanted to include a config file, it should be placed in a location (**may be in the Jenkins machine locally or what can be the best option?**).

Sample config file: server_config.txt

- test1 : https://jazz-test1.com
- test2 : https://jazz-test2.com
- test3 : https://jazz-test3.com

Once the user input is received , the job should access this file and check whether the server in the input link is present in the config file.
**If present call the bat script if not present throw an error , the server is not supported.**

Expected result:

- Input 1 : https://jazz-test3.com/web/projects/ABC
  Job should run
- Input 2 : https://jazz-test4.com/web/projects/ABC
  Job should fail with error message

**What is the best way of achieving this ?**
Can we do it directly from the pipeline or a separate script will be required to perform this ?
Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins supports configuration files stored on the controller via the **config-file-provider** plugin. See *Manage Jenkins | Managed Files* for the collection of managed configuration files.

You can add a JSON config file with id "test-servers" that stores your test server configuration:

```
{
  "test1":"https://jazz-test-1.com",
  "test2":"https://jazz-test-1.com"
}
```

Then the job pipeline would do something like:

```
servers = [:]

stage("Setup") {
  steps {
    configFileProvider([fileId:'test-servers', variable:'test_servers_json']) {
      script {
        // Read the json data from the file.
        echo "Loading configured servers from file '${test_servers_json}' ..." 
        servers = readJSON(file:test_servers_json)
      } 
    }
  }
}
stage('Test') {
  steps {
    script {
      // Check if 'server' is supported.
      if (!servers.containsKey(params.server)) {
        error "Unsupported server"
      }
      build job:'...', parameters:[...]
    }
  }
}
```